# How to fix NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/<int:pk>/']

Tags: python, django

I have tried everything i found on the internet which was similar to my problem, but it did not help. Please help if you know the answer.

I get an ERROR while trying to set up my post_detail page of my blog.

The ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/<int:pk>/']
```

***My post_list.html***

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Reminder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="/">Coder Reminder</a></h1>
        </div>

<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.blog.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**My post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

***My base.html***

```
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Reminder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Code Reminder</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

***my views.py***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, '/home/ud/PycharmProjects/blog/blog/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, '/home/ud/PycharmProjects/blog/blog/blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

***My urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

And finally my myblog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Please help me if you know the answer. I really tried everything but i cant find out my mistake.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found.
```

Which shows that the `pk` is evaluating to the empty string `''`.

Your URL tag is

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.blog.pk %}
```

That means you are trying to pass the post's blog's pk. But you almost certainly want the post's pk instead:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}
```

Secondly, you are using the old `url()` with the `path()` syntax (new in Django 2.0). Your urls should be:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem. Thats something i did because i wanted to try out every solution i then i forgot to delete the .blog.

Maybe you know the answer to my second question. It now displays every post i ever did. When i click on the URL of my post, i only shows me the right URL in the browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/5/), but it wont open the post in detail_view.

Comment: The problem is in your `urls.py`. See my updated answer.

Comment: But if i edit the url to path as you said, and edit the

from django.conf.urls import path

It then says that it cannot import name path.

Comment: I've made the changes you said and also started with python3 manage.py runserver and it then worked.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `path()` was added in Django 2.0, which only supports Python 3. If you had to use Python 2, you would have to use `url()` with Django 1.11, but since you are just starting you should use Python 3 with the latest Django (currently 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the older version of Python or Django. 
Try changing your *My urls.py* file as follow:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

Here it will help to parse the address properly. If it still doesn't work the try to replace following in *My post_list.html* file

Old:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.blog.pk %}
```

New:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}
```

Hope this will help!